Argument of \language@active@arg< has an extra }
I have the small MWE:
  \batchmode
  \documentclass[twoside]{book}
  \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Referencia \texorpdfstring{$<$}{<} }
\end{document}

And this results (with pdflatex) in the Error:
! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.5 \chapter{Referencia \texorpdfstring{$<$}{<} }

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.5 \chapter{Referencia \texorpdfstring{$<$}{<} }

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
...

Any suggestions on how to solve this in a general way?
(problem also occurs with other characters in textorpdfstring)

Try \deactivatequoting

Thanks for the suggestion, how would this look like for the given example?

Hmm... you reduced the MWE too much. Shouldn't you load hyperref as well? Anyway, < is made active by default in Spanish babel. My solution (given that I use unicode/utf8 encoding anyway) is to use always:
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Referencia \texorpdfstring{$<$}{<} }
\end{document}

That works almost everywhere.

Looks good. Indeed I did shorten the MWE quite a bit and the lines regarding hyperref and T1 had no effect on my initial problem, so I also stripped them.

Hmmm. If you remove hyperref the error is that \texorpdfstring is undefined...

Hey thank you a lot. This fixed my preamble.tex.
I have a preamble that sets the font, and i had to use this BEFORE the part where i setup the custom fonts.
